# Unit testing addError without doing DML

Tags: unit-test, adderror

We're big fans of doing unit tests using as little DML as possible, mocking SObjects using [various techniques](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator)

**Here's a simple example**

```
public class FoosService {
 public void doBar(Set<Id> ids) {
  ... do work ...
  ... oops ... throw BarException
 }
}

public class FoosDomain {

 public void onAfterInsert(SObject[] records) {
    try {
      FooService.doBar(new Map<Id,SObject>(records).keySet();
    }
    catch (FoosService.BarException e) {
      // apply addError(e) to relevant rows in records 
    }
 }
}
```

**In the unit testmethod**:

```
Foo__c[] mockFoos = new List<Foo__c> {
  new Foo__c(...),
  new Foo__c(...)  // causes exception in FoosService.doBar
};
new FoosDomain.onAfterInsert(mockFoos);
```

you want to be able to do this:

```
System.assertEquals(true,mockFoos[1].hasError(),'sb marked as error');
```

but there is no SObject method to see if a given SObject has had `addError(...)` applied to it.

**Known workarounds:**

fflib-apex-common fflib_SObjectDomain class which supports [this testable construction](https://andyinthecloud.com/category/apex/page/7/):

```
someSobject.addError(error('message',someSobject));

System.assertEquals('message',
    fflib_SObjectDomain.Errors.getAll()[1].message);
```

and as we're an fflib shop, I'm happy to use this

> Is there some other "trick" I don't know about to discover in an
>   assert that a non-DML'd SObject has had `addError` applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V50, [Apex SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm?search_text=haserrors) now has two new useful methods to solve this issue

- `Boolean hasErrors()`
- `Database.Error[] getErrors()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Weirdly enough, `ApexPages.hasMessages()` returns `true` when any record has had `addError` called on it.

```
Account record = new Account();
record.addError('Some message');
system.assert(ApexPages.hasMessages(), 'Informative message');
```

You won't be able to test *which* records have hit a validation, but you can tell if *any* have. Design your tests accordingly.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried this in anonymous apex but that fails.  Maybe doesn’t matter in test method context.

Comment: It worked for me in anonymous apex. I didn't post it here before trying it out. Strange.

Comment: This is probably undocumented behavior because it's not reliable? I've previously been told that in unit tests, they do not initialize the full "visualforce engine", so things that depend on it may not work. I didn't get any specifics, though, but I remember it was because of a bug I had.

Comment: @sfdcfox so - i run Adrian's snippet in DC and it works; I run in Illuminated Cloud IDE or Workbench anonymous Apex and I get `Error on line 3, column 1: System.FinalException: ApexPages.hasMessages can only be called from a Visualforce page
AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1`

Comment: @cropredy That's kind of what I'd expect. DC is actually a VF page under the covers.